# how to use a list name in system.assert in a test class?

Tags: unit-test

In my Test Class i have a list. I have to use it in System.assert() method

For Eg: If the list is not null , then the message is "Success".

How to do this ? 
Please provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

```
system.assertNotEquals(null, myList, 'Success');
```

You will find documentation on assert methods [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm)

Comment: So assertion failure messages make sense, `system.assertNotEquals(null, 'myList, Success');`.

Comment: Fair point, updated my post.

Comment: The 'Success' String in the [assertNotEquals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assertNotEquals) will be displayed when the assert fails. In this case when `myList` is `null` the test will fail with the message 'Success', which is a bit confusing.

Comment: Agreed, but that's what @ram451 wanted

Comment: What @ram451 was looking for was "_If the list is not null , then the message is "Success"_". You are displaying the "Success" failure message when the List is null

Comment: FYI, Just because your list is not null DOES not mean it is not Empty.

Comment: For complete testing of your list you should really do something like
If(myList != null || !myList.isEmpty() )
      System.assert(false, 'List is null Or Empty' );

Answer (score 0):

you can use system.assert() the same way as in the example below.

```
@isTest
public class testClass
{ 
    public static testMethod void mytest(){
    list<contact> listCon = new list<contact>();


        Account acc = new account();
        acc.name = 'Test';
        insert acc;
        contact con = new contact ();
        con.accountid = acc.id;
        con.lastname = acc.name;
        listCon.add(con);

 //this would throw an error  and cause your test to fail 
 System.assertEquals(listCon,null);
 //this would pass
       System.assertNotEquals(listCon,null,'success');

    insert listCon;
    }
    }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your [asserts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assertEquals) should always be expected value first and then actual value second.